winform gradual publish to clients machine
currently I am using ClickOnce to publish my winform application. Is there a way to also support gradual publish functionality so that I can manage to send updates to certain client machines for testing purpose ?

Check for updates programmatically:
Set conditions to decide whether to update based on the user's version and local configuration.
See: Manage updates for a ClickOnce application

This is only possible in the .net framework I suppose? How to do it in .NET ?

Currently, Checkfordetailedupdate() is not available in .NET. Follow up: https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/27#issuecomment-1314331853
